# How do you use a @ symbol in the name of a PHP object

Tags: php, object, reference

I've got an XML file that has the label @attributes for one of the names

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [PART_NUMBER] => ABC123
```

I want to make a reference to this object like $product->@attributes['part_number'] but of course the @ symbol causes an error.

So how do I reference this item in the object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, in the case of SimpleXML, you'd call the `$product->attributes()` method as defined in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). That will give you an array mapping attribute names to values.

Answer (score 7):

`$obj`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@id] => Hello
    [$] => World!
)
```

To access `@id` and `$`:

```
echo $obj->{'@id'};
echo ' ';
echo $obj->{'$'};
```

Answer (score 2):

`$product[0]['PART_NUMBER']` should work.

If you got more than one attribute, you should use `$product->attributes()` in a `foreach`

[attributes in SimpleXML manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SimpleXML objects, is already have an `attributes` method built into it (without the `@` sign) -- use it like this: `$product->attributes('part_number');`

If you're trying to create your own objects to map to the XML, then as you already found out, you can't use the `@` symbol in a PHP variable name (nor any other symbol except underscore).

I'd suggest simply using `$product->attributes['part_number']` (ie without the `@` symbol at all) and mapping it inside your class.

If you *really* need to map it into your variable names, the best you can really hope for would be some kind of replacement string that you can swap in and out as you convert between the two formats.

eg: `$product->at__attributes['part_number']`

But that's not really a particularly good solution, IMHO.